# Intercommunicator in MPI c

Tags: c, mpi

I want just to create an intercommunicator between two groups B and C which have 2 intercommunicator. I get an invalid communicator error. Where did I have a mistake in my simple code?

```
        #include<stdio.h>
  #include<errno.h>
  #include<stdlib.h>
  #include<string.h>

  #include"mpi.h"

  int main(){
    MPI_Comm a,b,c;
    MPI_Group A,C,B;
    MPI_Comm com1,com2;

    int size ,subsize=3,rank;

    MPI_Init(NULL,NULL);


    a = MPI_COMM_WORLD;

    MPI_Comm_size( a , &size );
    MPI_Comm_rank( a , &rank );


    MPI_Comm_group( a , &A );

    MPI_Comm_group( a , &B );

    MPI_Comm_create(a,B,&b);


    MPI_Group_size(B,&subsize);
    MPI_Group_rank(B,&subsize);


    printf("/////////////////////////////%d\n", MPI_Intercomm_create(a,0,b,1,20,&c));
    MPI_Group_free(&A);
    MPI_Group_free(&B);
    MPI_Comm_free(&a);
    MPI_Comm_free(&b);
    MPI_Comm_free(&c);
    MPI_Finalize();

    printf("END\n");

    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: `b` is used uninitialized and your code does not even compile. Why don't you simply `MPI_Comm_split()` to generate intra-communicators `a` and `b` ? (read you do not need `MPI_Group` here)

Comment: becauz i must create a function who make a lot of split or cluster of proc and i guess is better to this way

Comment: MPI_Intercomm_create(b,0,a,0,20,c); change it to  MPI_Intercomm_create(b,0,a,0,20,&c);

Comment: First, you should edit your question with code that compiles and has no uninitialized variables. And do not hesitate to explain your rationale for thinking you’d better do things this way.

Comment: 20 is just a tag between pair of communicator , alos how can i  reedit my code  plz ??

Comment: There should be an `edit` link just under your question

Comment: any answers............................. ?

Comment: `B` is used uninitialized, and the code does not even compile.

Comment: you are right cauze i use the MPI_Comm_group( b,B); with a void communicator which impact the value of B. i changed my code but i still have an issue it s the cusrsor get block on my terminal i guess the MPI_Intercomm_create is the pb.

Comment: forget about `MPI_Group`, it is unnecessary here. From the MPI 3.1 chapter 6.6.2 *Overlap of local and remote groups that are bound into an inter-communicator is prohibited. If there is overlap, then the program is erroneous and is likely to deadlock.*. For example, `MPI_Comm_split()` produce communicators with groups that do not overlap.

Comment: so in which matter i can divide the world of mpi to cluster (kind of groups of proc ) and make them connected trough intercommunicator ?

Comment: Try writing a simple program that has even ranks in one group and odd ranks in the other group of the inter-communicator. Or simply `MPI_Comm_spawn()`

Answer (score 0):

this seond code is working fine but i still want to know, is it possible to bind between (a) and (b) inter-communicators via the (d) comm.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

#include"mpi.h"

int main(){
  MPI_Comm a,b,c1,c2,d;
  MPI_Group A,C,B;
  MPI_Comm com1,com2;

  int *flg;
  int size ,subsize=3,rank,color;

  MPI_Init(0,0);


  a = MPI_COMM_WORLD;

  MPI_Comm_size( a , &size );
  MPI_Comm_rank( a , &rank );

  color = rank %2;

  MPI_Comm_split(MPI_COMM_WORLD,color,rank,&a);
  MPI_Intercomm_create(a,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,1-color,20,&c1);

  MPI_Comm_split(MPI_COMM_WORLD,color,rank,&b);
  MPI_Intercomm_create(b,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,1-color,20,&c2);

 // MPI_Intercomm_create(a,0,b,1,20,&d);

  MPI_Comm_test_inter(a,flg);
  printf(" this comm %d \n",*flg);
  MPI_Comm_free(&a);
  MPI_Comm_free(&b);
//        MPI_Comm_free(&c);

  MPI_Finalize();

  printf("END\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve exactly ? you can simply make a sketch with all your (expected) communicators (both intra and extra) and upload a photo.